# game maker studio local save path on mobiles

Tags: android, file, path, save, local

I have an app and I transferred a file to it using TCP. I then want to save this file on the device in a folder that can be accessed using an app like a "file manager" or when browsing the phone when connected to the PC via USB.

So we have the file to write using `file_bin_write(path)`

but we need the path:

```
if os_type==os_windows 
 path=string_replace(environment_get_variable("APPDATA"),"Roaming","Local\")+game_project_name+"\"+name;
  else
  if os_type==os_winphone
    path="\Phone\Downloads\"+name;//set path to save
  else
   path=working_directory+"\"+name;//set path to save
```